# How to remove ?___from_store=de on the url? in Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, multistore, url, store-view, magento2.2.3

how to remove ?___from_store=de on the url?

```
http://exsample.com/en/?___from_store=de
```

Please post genuine ans!

## Updated after @Andreas von Studnitz Suggestion. (See File Structure)

In Custom Module di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Store\Model\Store">
        <plugin name="cremove_query_string" type="Custom\Module\Plugin\Store\Model\Store" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
```

In Custom\Module\Plugin\Store\Model\Store.php

```
namespace Custom\Module\Plugin\Store\Model;

public function beforeGetCurrentUrl(\Magento\Store\Model\Store $store, $fromStore=true)
{
    return [false];
}
```

Comment: In magento backend you can find the option to add store code to url. In that case your will not get the query string.

Comment: Yes, I know this(already set to yes) but in my case query string coming after store code(en). @ Priyank

Comment: @GagandeepSingh you done this? can you please share your code/module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from `\Magento\Store\Model\Store::getCurrentUrl`:

```
public function getCurrentUrl($fromStore = true)
{...
```

If you change the default value of the variable `$fromStore` from `true` to `false`, the parameter won't show up any more. You can archieve that with a `before` plugin as follows:

```
public function beforeGetCurrentUrl(Store $store, $fromStore = true)
{
    return [false];
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, Please see my updated ans for all in detail who facing problem like this!

Comment: @GagandeepSingh So does my suggestion work for you or doesn't it? I tested it on my machine...

Comment: Yes, Its worked.